# EJB remote client throwing nullpointerexception : Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider

Tags: java, ejb

I have a stateless bean

```
 @Stateless
 public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Override
  public int add(int a, int b) {
return a+b;
  }
    @Override
   public int sub(int a, int b) {
return a-b;
   }
   @Override
   public int mul(int a, int b) {
return a*b;
  }
   @Override
    public float div(int a, int b) {
return a/b;
   }
    }
```

I have deployed this on glassfish with interface annotated with @Remote

```
  @Remote
  public interface Calculator extends Serializable{
  public int add(int a, int b)throws RemoteException;
  public int sub(int a, int b)throws RemoteException;
   public int mul(int a, int b)throws RemoteException;
   public float div(int a, int b)throws RemoteException;
  }
```

When I am trying to access it by the client i.e. a java desktop application:
It is throwing a NullpointerException

Client code:

```
      MyClient client= new MyClient();
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
  props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

  // glassfish default port value will be 3700, 
  // but im using tcpviewer to redirect my 50005 port to 3700
  props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

  InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props);

 client.cart = (ShoppingCart) context
        .lookup("java:global/EJBDemo2EAR/EJBDemo2/CalculatorImpl!com.java.stateless.Calculator");
System.out.println("In doget");
client.cart.buy("soap", 12);
client.cart.getCartContents();
```

Error is:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.java.client.MyClient.main(MyClient.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/EJBDemo2EAR/EJBDemo2/CalculatorImpl!com.java.stateless.Calculator' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup

Comment: Have added gf-client and appserv-rt.jar to the classpath, but not working

Answer (score 2):

In context.lookup just pass the fully qualified interface name:

```
client.cart=(ShoppingCart)context.lookup("com.java.stateless.Calculator");
```

Comment: can you see JNDI entree for your ejb? Please follow the steps to check whether your ejb is listed in the JNDI tree of your glass fish server. If the entry is there, you should be able to look it up. Your code seems to be correct.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/list-jndi-entries.htm#GSRFM00178

Comment: I can see in logs the jndi name when I start the server:                                                                                                                Portable JNDI names for EJB ShoppingCartBean: [java:global/EJBProjectOneEAR/EJ
BProjectOne/ShoppingCartBean, java:global/EJBProjectOneEAR/EJBProjectOne/Shoppin
gCartBean!org.jboss.tutorial.stateful.bean.ShoppingCart]|#]                                                                                                                  But not visible when I do list-jndi-entries